# Pytest parametrize + Fixtures

Tags: python, flask, pytest, fixtures, parametrized-testing

I am using fixtures to mock my requests.

I am also using `@pytest.mark.parametrize()` to add arguments to my tests.

I can do this:

```
def test_format(mock_api):
```

I can do this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "format",
    [
        ("xxx"),
        ("yyy"),
    ],
)
def test_format(format):
```

but I can't do this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "my_mock",
    [
        (mock_api),
        (None),
    ],
)
def test_format(my_mock):
```

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

[UPDATE] here is my fixture:

```
@fixture(scope="function")
def mock_api(app):
    app.test_client_class = build_test_client_class(
        {
            "Authorization": "XXX",
            "X-API-KEY": "YYY",
        }
    )
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client
```

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Comment: NameError: name 'mock_api' is not defined

Comment: This error is kind of self explanatory... where and how did you define `mock_api`?

Comment: it's defined in test config

Comment: it works as a separate fixture when I do: def test_api(mock_api): but not as a test parameter.